# Java heap space Xmx Xms on a vServer with burstable RAM

Tags: java, performance, jvm-arguments, minecraft

We run a Minecraft server that relies on Java on a vServer that has 1GB guaranteed RAM and 4GB burstable RAM.

We run Debian 6.0 (Squeeze) Minimal (64Bit) with a lighttpd webserver with php/mySQL alongside the actual Minecraft server. We currently have everything set up to stay within our 1GB guaranteed RAM, but it seems as if we are not taking advantage of the burstable RAM this way, nor do we know how (and if?) we should do so.

We currently have our server loading with the following string:

```
 /opt/java/jre/bin/java -Xmx880M -Xms880M
                        -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
                        -XX:+CMSIncrementalPacing
                        -XX:ParallelGCThreads=2
                        -XX:+AggressiveOpts
                        -jar craftbukkit.jar nogui
```

We allocate 880M for minecraft (we think?), the rest is reserved for the system, webserver etc. How could we optimize this setup? Does it make sense to allocate this inital startup over the 1GB and well into our burstable RAM? Is there a way for Java or the system to handle this themselves, as in allocating more than 880M when it's needed at peak times, with a max of 4GB? Since the burstable RAM isn't guaranteed, what will happen if it's not available when it would need it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> How could we optimize this setup?

It depends.  You should first profile the memory usage of this process.  Add

`-verbose:gc:file=gc_results.out`

to your command line.  You can open the resulting gc datafile with a tool like [HPjmeter](http://www.hpjmeter.com).  You should tune the heap based on average/peak memory usage.  There is no one size fits all policy thats 'optimal'.  As a start, inspect how much time you're spending in garbage collection on average.  A good rule of thumb is < 7%.  How often are you triggering a Full GC?  Is your heap full of long living objects, or is it being bombarded with lots of short lived objects?  These questions should drive your decision making.

Comment: I will be very honest: I have never heard of GC or know what it is.

Comment: GC is garbage collection.  Java has an automatic memory management model.

Comment: I also have no control over the actual process (the minecraft server) running on it, nor do I know the exact technical details about how it handles objects and such things. It doesn't require the full 880M at all times, memory usage seems to fluctuate according to the number of players online and can peak when under heavy load and usage. If it peaks and it doesn't have enough memory the minecraft server will simply crash. The problem is that it can't peak beyond the 880 with our current setup even though the more than plenty burstable RAM should allow us to handle those peaks.

Comment: How are you adding the command line options:
-Xmx880M -Xms880M
                        -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
                        -XX:+CMSIncrementalPacing
                        -XX:ParallelGCThreads=2
                        -XX:+AggressiveOpts

However you're doing that, add the option I gave you, let the server run for some time, then collect the output file and analyze it.  Anything else that you do is complete conjecture.

Answer (score 0):

A server will spend most of its time taking the maximum RAM allotted.  My understanding of "burstable" RAM is--don't count on it, but if you briefly require it it might not crash.  In this case, you don't want your JVM hanging on to burstable RAM.  The configuration you've specified seems about right.